# First cell wrong size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pftableviewcell

I need to get the first cell in my tableView to be a different size from the rest. The rest of my cells are all under the class CustomPFTableViewCell, but the first one is a different cell so its under the class FirstPFTableViewCell, both of which extend from the class PFTableViewCell. Right now, I just used an if depending on the indexPath.row for whether or not the cell was the first cell. When its not it will load data for the cell from Parse.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row >= 1){
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomPFTableViewCell!

    print("Loading Parse Database Files...")
    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let name = object?["Name"] as? String {
        cell?.nameTextLabel?.text = name
        print("Loading " + name)
    }
    if let author = object?["authorName"] as? String {
        cell?.authorTextLabel?.text = author
    }
    if let likes = object?["Likes"] as? Int {
        let stringVal = String(likes)
        cell?.numLikes.text = stringVal
    }
    if let descrip = object?["Description"] as? String {
        cell?.descriptionHolder = descrip
    }
    let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "Unloaded")
    cell.customFlag.image = initialThumbnail
    if let thumbnail = object?["imageCover"] as? PFFile {
        cell.customFlag.file = thumbnail
        cell.customFlag.loadInBackground()
    }
        return cell
    }

    print("Finished loading!")



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCell") as! PFTableViewCell
    return cell


}
```

The end is empty because I'm not sure how to go about changing the one/first cell's size. (In the Interface Builder its set to 60). I guess the most important part in solving this is this:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCell") as! PFTableViewCell
    return cell


}
```

Comment: You probably have to use [`tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to play with the size of the cell you have to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    return firstCellHeight
} else {
    return customCellHeight
}
```